# Rails ajax form display

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have two models, :groups and :shots I am trying to add a shot to a group via ajax. Here are the relevant files...

```
    #app/views/groups/show.html.erb
    <%= link_to 'New Shot', new_shot_path(group_id: @group), id: "new_shot", remote: true %></br>

    #app/views/shots/new.js.erb
    $('#new_shot').hide().after('<%= j render("form") %>');

#app/views/shots/new.html.erb
<h1>New shot</h1>
<%= render 'form' %>
<%= link_to 'Back', shots_path %>

#app/views/shots/_form.html.erb
<%= form_for(@shot) do |f| %>
  <% if @shot.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@shot.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this shot from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @shot.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :group_id, :value => params[:group_id] %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label 'Comedian' %><br />
    <%=
      @comedians = Comedian.all
      collection_select(:shot, :comedian_id, @comedians, :id, :name)
    %>
  </div>
    <%= f.file_field :pic %>
    <%= image_tag @shot.pic.url(:thumb) %>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Everything looks good in the console...

```
Started GET "/shots/new?group_id=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-02-25 10:09:19 -0500
Processing by ShotsController#new as JS
  Parameters: {"group_id"=>"1"}
  Comedian Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "comedians".* FROM "comedians" 
  Rendered shots/_form.html.erb (12.1ms)
  Rendered shots/new.html.erb within layouts/application (12.7ms)
Completed 200 OK in 93ms (Views: 52.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.6ms)
```

Its just nothing renders on the page. Any ideas what I'm missing? I know there are some issue with paperclip (which I am using) but I tried removing those references from the page and I get the same result. Also, I am using twitter bootstrap. Not sure if that could be causing an issue.

Comment: You are most likely missing a div element with id 'new_shot' on your page

Comment: You are suggesting this should be in app/views/groups/show.html.erb?

Comment: What version of Rails are you using? Can you also include the `ShotsController`.

Comment: Rails 3.2x, and I have not added anything to the shots controller outside of the normal scaffolding.

Answer (score 0):

So...

My fix was to modify the shots_controller to remove the respond to block for html and json from this...

```
  def new
    @shot = Shot.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @shot }
    end
  end
```

to this...

```
  def new
    @shot = Shot.new
  end
```

Could someone explain why this needs to be removed for ajax to work?